# Maven & architecture - how to build all available architectures?

Tags: maven, maven-2

I'm actually trying to compile some native code, but that I think that has to wait for a moment.  Please consider the following as building up to resolving Native builds with Maven-NAR-pluggin.

We have 64 bit windows machines currently which are quite capable of also compiling 32 bit software. (yes I know, still waiting for the 128 bit)

**How do we configure Maven pluggins / POM to compile both?**
aka override the architecture as provided from the JRE that was found in JAVA_HOME

```
C:\Data\dev\zlib\minizip>mvn -X compile
+ Error stacktraces are turned on.
Apache Maven 2.2.1 (r801777; 2009-08-06 15:16:01-0400)
Java version: 1.6.0_31
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_31\jre
Default locale: en_AU, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 7" version: "6.1" arch: "amd64" Family: "windows"

c:\Data\dev\zlib\miniunzip>mvn -X compile
+ Error stacktraces are turned on.
Apache Maven 2.2.1 (r801777; 2009-08-06 15:16:01-0400)
Java version: 1.6.0_20
Java home: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_20\jre
Default locale: en_AU, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 7" version: "6.1" arch: "x86" Family: "windows"
```

We may also have a need to compile some modules to different JRE versions due to being a loaded library used in JRE 1.3/1.4/1.5/1.6

**Is it possible to configure Maven POM to have profile differences or build differences based on the JRE version we are compiling to, or do we have to have 4 POM?**

**Is it possible to configure Maven to Run tests using an alternate JRE to that executing the Maven build?**